# App store Rejects App for IPV6 network support on iOs 10

Tags: ios, iphone, titanium, appcelerator, ipv6

I got an app rejection mail from apple which is below,

**We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad and iPhone running iOS 10.0.2 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.
Specifically, app remains on splash screen upon launch.**

Based on their request i have created the NAT64 network on my Mac and shared that internet for the iPhone 5S device 10.0.2 os version , App was working fine,

But apple says its not working with IPv6 
Can anyone confirm that do i need to check anything else?

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778878/ipv6-error-on-submitting-app-to-apple/39868314#39868314)

**Environments:**
Appcelerator Studio Ti SDK 5.1.0 GA
XCode Version 6.3

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you check this below link for this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38499156/app-rejected-with-ios-ipv6-network

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just Read the mail you got from apple people. Answer will be there only.
Use wireshark to know what exactly your network doing.

Also to understand the problem better use wireshark for analyzing what is going on - create an network as outlined in that session and see what happens on the wifi port

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/719/

for more info check @[Sean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2467825/sean-thielen) Answer

> After quite a bit of stress, I can confirm that the issue was a problem with our backend not being correctly configured for IPv6. Apparently, AWS doesn't support IPv6, nor IPv6-only DNS through Route53. I ended up moving all the internet facing bits of the backend away from AWS for the time being. I wanted to leave this up because I think there are probably going to be others who find themselves with similar problems as people start submitting updates past the IPv6-only restriction. The best tool I found for testing server/dns readiness has been: http://ready.chair6.net/

Comment: Hi @Deepak Carpenter,  Thanks for your quick reply, I have tested our server with http://ready.chair6.net/ and it fails for the IPV6 network connectivity, But the app was working fine with the same server which we have tested by creating NAT64 network (for IPV6 network) on our iPhone  5S  device with 10.0.2 OS version,   Can you guide for the below, Do we need to resubmit the app to app store or contact with the apple technical support.   Or else do we need to configure our Server to support the IPV6 network?

Comment: @SilambarasanRaman in our case we resubmitted the app & it worked. but it is better to inform apple team too.

Comment: Thanks will contact apple team with Working video before resubmit to app store

Comment: Hi @Deepak we are also facing the same issue.Review from Apple is  "We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad and iPhone running iOS 10.2 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network" .  Our old app is approved and working fine.We updated our xcode to 8.2. When we upload the new app built with this xcode got rejected.Could please help in resolving this issue

Comment: @HansikaPenugonda Check with your back end team whether they did some changes, Its your server ipv6 compatibility issue. 
Check Here :
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#app-completeness
In case you want to know more about your app rejection, you can send a mail to appreview@apple.com, they are really helpful.

Comment: @Deepak our older app is connecting to same server. Apple approved.

Answer (score 0):

Request your hosting provider to assign your server IPv6 as well and they will not charge you for this. This will resolve your IPv6 issues.

In my case I contacted the hosting provider about this issue and they said IPv6 is not assigned to my server I requested them and asked for the cost, they said it is free of cost and will assign it now. I think hosting companies have to assign IPv6 to all servers but they are assigning it on priority bases for those who are facing this issue.

So better you contact hosting provider for your IPv6 assignment.