# App Rejected with reason that app does not support IPV6 protocol

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

My application is coded in swift 3, Xcode 8.2.1, With deployment target 10. Yesterday I submitted my first version of the app. Its Rejected unfortunately ;(

I'm using third pods as

```
Using AFNetworking (3.1.0)
Using GoogleMaps (2.2.0)
Using ReachabilitySwift (3)
```

Apple team says that app is not working in iPad with Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network and app did not determine current location.

Can anyone help me? what should I do to support iPV 6.

Comment: My car doesn't work because the mechanic says it's broken.  Do you have any code related to location and networking?  Does it work on your devices?  Have you yourself tested in on an iPad?

Comment: Everything is working fine with my iPad mini, iPhone 6 and all simulators.

Comment: If you can prove that with screenshots, try submitting an appeal.

Comment: Yes defiantly, I have well test the app with all possible scenarios with and without permissions

Comment: Could be an issue with the backend.  Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39872072/app-store-rejects-app-for-ipv6-network-support-on-ios-10?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `ReachabilitySwift`. You have to use the `Reachability` class from Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Reachability_Reachability_h.html

When you create an Objective-C class in a Swift project, Xcode suggest it to create a `Bridging Header Class` to use Objective-C in Swift.

I had that problem a lot of times, I strong recommend you always use `Reachability` class direct from Apple and not from other open source projects from internet.

Comment: Can you explain why `ReachabilitySwift` is the problem?

Comment: @sbarow I used the same libraries you listed and Apple rejected a lot of time my apps. When I replaced `ReachablitySwift` for `Reachability` class from Apple, the issue was solved. This is whats worked for me.