# Creating Classic loadbalancer to support IPV6 on AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, ipv6, elastic-load-balancer

on AWS can someone enlist step to support IPV6? does AAAA record is enough? our app works on NAT64 network we have just AAAA record which is mapped to classic loadbalancer it is not resolving does they check connectivity also while reviewing app?

it has be asked here but no proper reesponse
[IPv6 App Store Rejection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37637818/ipv6-app-store-rejection/)

Comment: Can you make use of ELBv2 (aka ALB) instead of your Classic ELB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found is to use Cloudfront. Cloudfront supports IPV6. Just use your ELB as a source for Cloudfront.

A must read to [configure it](https://steinn.org/post/ipv6-with-cloudfront-on-aws/)