# Apple App Rejected Due to IPV6 Crash

Tags: ios, iphone

I have created an ios app using web services of Dotnet and it was launched successfully 1 month ago. I connected my app with web services Synchronously.
Now I have changed the app and app is connecting with web Services ASynchronously and put the app on appstore. But Apple rejected the app saying it is crashing on iPV6.
Can someone guide me, how to resolve this issue. As my server is iPV4 based, I am not able to upgrade my server.

Comment: `As my server is iPV4 based, I am not able to upgrade my server`. You should support IPv6. no other way!

Comment: I believe your web host must be reachable in an ipv6 only environment; so not having the capability won't do you much good.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IPv6 App Store Rejection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37637818/ipv6-app-store-rejection)

Answer (score 1):

I had faced same issue. Mine was also rejected due to IPV6. Check below two things for your application:

1) Make sure you API link which you used in your application, doesn't have any ip address. If you calling API using IPAddress then your application will rejected.

2) Do testing your application using IPV6 network thorugh your system. Here is the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1).

If your application is fullfill both testcase, then don't do any thing, just right comment in iTuneConnect and told them that my application is running in IPV6 network. Can you please guide to find my issue? If possible then can I have a call with your representative?

So they ask your contact detail and give you call and your issue will resvoled. I have wasted around 20 days to solved this issue. But apple representative told that this is them internal issue.

So my humble advice to contact Apple representative as soon as possible and your issue will resolve without doing anything.

Comment: I am not using IP address in my application. I am using URL like this 'www.testsite.com'. I have made my Mac on iPV6 and run the app on simulator but it is stuck on the first page where it is logging in the user.

Comment: Create IPV6 network using link which I provided. If your application is working in created network then comment to get a call from apple representative.

Comment: Then don't bother, just ask Apple Representative for call. Its apple internal issue.

Comment: Even if it is stuck on the first page of application using iPV6, Still you think I have to call apple. I think they will say simply 'Your application is not working on iPV6'. Please advice.

Comment: Are you getting any error from server or it will stuck?

Comment: Test application in device.

Comment: Can you please provide your api link? So I can check it out at my end.

Comment: i got stuck with the same,i am using hard coaded api but apple is saying app is crashing,creash location is after going two or more view controller then how api is hiting on ipv6 to go till crash location.