# IPv6 Network connection issue in iPhone

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, ipv6

We are using AWS server. As it is not supporting IPv6 network protocol, Apple rejected my app.

I want to know if I can do anything on app side to resolve this issue apart from switching to the other server.

I am using `NSURLSession`.

Thanks

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42198589/apple-app-rejected-due-to-ipv6-crash/42203030#42203030) click.
Hope this link is help you.

Comment: If you app is calling server with domain name, it should not create any problem. are you using IP address anywhere? in reachability class?

Comment: No, I am using domain name only. IP address in not used anywhere in the app.

Comment: You need to debug your application. This has nothing to do with your server. Read the notice that Apple sent you.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually had the same problem before. At first I tested my app by the suggested tests by apple (you can find them on this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1)). However, the tests were successful so I couldn't find my problem. Then I simply contacted the Apple Support saying that I ran all tests and everything seemed fine on my side and they simply accepted my build.

So my suggestion would be to ran the tests suggested by Apple, and if the results are positive then simply contact the Apple support.

Hope that was useful!