# Titanium iOS app was rejected due the IPv6 incompatibility

Tags: ios, titanium, ipv6, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

Titanium SDK: 5.2.1

xCode : 6.1.1

OS x : 10.9.5

to call some API's i am using this simple a sync call:

```
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload : function() {
        this.responseText;
    },
    onerror : function(e) {
        alert(e);
    },
    timeout : 1000 * 30
});
var url = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.send();
```

Butt [Apple](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) send me something like this,

> Thank you for your response. Please find the attached screenshot of
>   the activity indicator spinning indefinitely after launching the app
>   on an iPhone and iPad.
>
> It would be appropriate to run your app on a device while connected to
>   an IPv6 network to identify any issue, then revise and resubmit your
>   app for review.
>
> Once this issue is resolved, we can continue with the review.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it has nothing to do with your app specifically, or Titanium. But in this case it is your backend/DNS configured incorrectly.

You can find more info in this question: [IPv6 App Store Rejection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37637818/ipv6-app-store-rejection)

Comment: I tested my APIs. It fails these three tests, 

DNS (IPv6 NS) 
DNS (MX Record) 
DNS (Glue)

Result for those three are WARN. Is that issue that apple is rejecting my App?
It's is necessary to pass domain all the tests.
on http://ready.chair6.net/?

Comment: I believe so, yes