# IPv6 app store rejection for app querying IPv4 server

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store, ipv6

My App for Iphone/Ipad connects to a server, transmits data from this server by JSON and shows the data to the user in form of lists and graphs. The server in question "https://www.myfxbook.com" is not IPv6 compliant.

Apple's Appstore-review team keeps rejecting my app since  they can't reach this server (which does not have an AAAA-record) within their test set-up.

I followed their advice to set up and test IPv6 connectivity in my place where I found that from my IPv6 network I could reach the IPv4-server. But obviously the Appstore-review team uses a pure IPv6 setup

using the "dig" command I found the following response within my NAT64 network

```
iMac:myfxtract XXXXXX$ dig -t AAAA https://www.myfxtract.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> -t AAAA https://www.myfxtract.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 55233
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
 ;https://www.myfxtract.com.    IN  AAAA

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
com.            600 IN  SOA a.gtld-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com.    1492237025 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 30 msec
;; SERVER: 2001:730:3e62::53#53(2001:730:3e62::53)
;; WHEN: Sat Apr 15 08:17:26 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 116
```

If anyone has the same situation and could offer me some advice on the issue ? Been "talking" to Apple-hotlines for weeks to no avail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to be resilient about the difference between testing within own NAT64 and the Appreview network. My app was finally accepted without further comment

Comment: What did the issue end up being, exactly?

Comment: The issue is.. the server I am querying is not IPv6 compliant... AppStore Team can't reach IPv4 addresses. My app crashes in AppStore setting but not in real world... I had to keep insisting and proving that there is no problem

Comment: Thanks I see.  Yikes, had to keep insisting - that doesn't sound fun.

Comment: What should I do please help ?

Answer (score -1):

Please check below link for support for ipv6

[IPv6 App Store Rejection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37637818/ipv6-app-store-rejection)

After that please verify below points in your app

In the app rejection, if there are any crash logs are attached then please symbolicate it and try to find the exact location where your app is crashing. For symbolicating crash please check below link

1.https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

2.[Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports)

Please check with your server for supporting ipv6 environment.

Check for third party libraries which are used in your app. And make sure that these libraries are ready to use in ipv6 environment

Test your app in ipv6 environment. To test your app in ipv6 environment please check below link about how to test your app in ipv6 environment

1.https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html

2.https://developer.apple.com/support/ipv6/

If above all points are checked and your app is working fine. Then please contact apple for rejection of app.

Comment: Thanks for answering... that is the standard-answer you get from Apple. I checked my app with IPv6 (in NAT64-setting described in documents 1 and 2).

non-IP6-server gets called and the app works. But within Apples settings there seems to be no DNS-resolution for IPv4-server