# Apple App Store IPV6 Requirement

Tags: ios, iphone, ipv6, appstore-approval

I am going to publish an app on Apple Store then I came to know about IPV6 rejection issue. My app only support for IPV4 and on this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html) I found that app should support IPV6.

So my question is that, Is it compulsory that app must support for both IPV4 & IPV6?

Sorry if looks as a foolish question but I am looking for a Apple link & more detail before getting rejected from Apple.

Comment: What limits your app to IPv4? Do you have any hardcoded IPv4 addresses? Or is it some dependency that is not compatible with IPv6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to worry about IPv6 support, if you've not set hard-core IPv4 IP address in your web server/service url connection.

This Apple document will help you: [Supporting IPv6-only Networks](https://developer.apple.com/support/ipv6/)

All apps submitted to the App Store must support IPv6-only networking. A majority of apps will not require any changes as IPv6 is already supported by NSURLSession and CFNetwork APIs. ***However, if your app utilizes IPv4-specific APIs or hard-coded IP addresses, you will need to make changes***. Be sure to test for IPv6 compatibility before submitting your app to the App Store for review.

However, Apple guides in [Testing your app in an IPv6-only environment](https://developer.apple.com/support/ipv6/):

*You should test your app on an IPv6-only network. If you don’t have one, you can set up a test network by following the instructions in [Test for IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Compatibility Regularly](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1).*

Following SO reference, faced similar problem, may guide you:

- [IPv6 App Store Rejection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37637818/ipv6-app-store-rejection)

Comment: This answer isn't completely correct. There are more ways that you can be incompatible with IPv6 networks besides hard-coding IPv4 addresses. It really depends on which API you're using. The high-level APIs take care of the abstraction for the developer, but when low-level APIs are used the developer has the responsibility to do it right.

Comment: @SanderSteffann can you please explain more?

Comment: @SanderSteffann - You are welcomed to improve quality (completeness) of this answer. Please share your inputs are editing this answer or posting your own answer. Thanks for your remark.