# How do I fix, App Store Rejected app for external tester: Reason: Performance: App Completeness?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, appstore-approval

From Apple
2. 1 Performance: App Completeness
Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad￼ running iOS 12.1.1 on Wi-Fi.

Specifically, we were unable to connect to the internet￼

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please run your app on a device to identify any issues, then revise and resubmit your app for review.

If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to this message in Resolution Center to provide information on how these features were intended to work.

For new apps, uninstall all previous versions of your app from a device, then install and follow the steps to reproduce the issue. For updates, install the new version as an update to the previous version, then follow the steps to reproduce the issue.

Resources

For information about testing your app and preparing it for review, please see Technical Note TN2431: App Testing Guide.

For a networking overview, please review About Networking. For a more specific overview of App Review’s IPv6 requirements, please review the IPv6 and App Review discussion on the Apple Developer Forum.

**Please help to solve this issue and enable app for external tester or generate public url for app.**

Disclaimer: We are checking internet connectivity on login and its working good in iPad and iPhone both.

Comment: [tag:appstore-approval] is off topic here.

Comment: Have you tested your app on a pure ipv6 network?

Comment: Most probably you do "internet connectivity check" wrong. You should post some code.

Comment: @TimurBernikowich this my code for internet checking..

 NetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
            flags = (NetworkReachabilityFlags)Reachability.InternetConnectionStatus();
            //return (flags &  NetworkReachabilityFlags.IsWWAN) != 0;
            if(flags==NetworkReachabilityFlags.Reachable)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal question about policy compliance, not about programming as defined by the [help]. Legal questions can be asked on https://law.stackexchange.com/, instead. Questions specific to app rejection policies should be directed to Apple support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue in your code:

```
(flags == NetworkReachabilityFlags.Reachable)
```

should be:

```
(flags & NetworkReachabilityFlags.Reachable) != 0
```

Comment: We have created a NAT64 network to test IPv6 support and found our rest api throwing an exception to connection failure.

Comment: I just wrote my suggestion based on code you provided.

Comment: Yes we can change it as you suggested but please tell me one thing, we have to upgrade my rest api services to IPv6 or any other stuff?

Comment: @SumitMishra in most cases it should be just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Apple is testing your app in ipv6 connection. so it may get timeout or network not connected errors.

you can check this similar question and can debug your issue.

[IPv6 App Store Rejection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37637818/ipv6-app-store-rejection)

[Apple App Store IPV6 Requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339092/apple-app-store-ipv6-requirement)

Comment: Yes it is  IPv6 issue. We have created a NAT64 network to test IPv6 support and found our rest api throwing an exception to connection failure. Please tell me we have to update my app or rest api?

Comment: check if you have hard-core IPv4 IP address in your web server/service url connection or not, if it is then your domain/server need to be compatible with the ipv6 and you need to use domain name instead of hardcoded ip address.

Comment: Okay we are working on it..